# Must I forsake my regular earlier minyan to pray around sunrise?

Tags: tefilla, halacha-theory, zemanim, shacharis-morning-prayer

The ideal time for praying the morning service is to have the Amidah at sunrise. [O Ch 89 (1)](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.89?lang=bi)  . The Mishnah Beruroh (1) there says that in the winter when one goes to synagogue early, one should still wait for sunrise. But if one has to travel or there is some other unavoidable circumstance one may pray earlier.

There is a concept of having a fixed place for praying [O Ch 90 (19)](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.90?lang=bi).

If one's synagogue has three morning services. At this time of the year only the last one gives one the possibility of saying the  Amidah at sunrise or later. (The others have the  Amidah before sunrise.)

On a normal day, one must pray at an early time in order to be at work on time. So one has a regular minyan that he attends. On a day when he can go to work later, is he obliged to go to the later (and not his regular) service where he may not feel so comfortable?

Can we extend the concept of “fixed place for praying” to mean the same time of service? Do we find any sources dealing with this question because my friend asked this question of his Rabbi and was told he could stick with his regular minyan?

Comment: http://hirhurim.blogspot.com/2009/03/shacharis-tips-of-unemployed.html

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3760/closure-of-complex-scenario-questions

Comment: This is an interesting question, that I wonder regarding *Vasikin* minyanim this time of year in the Northeast U.S. (among other places). Apparently, there is a leniency to daven at *misheyakir* - I don't know, offhand, the exact timing of this. And, I gather that if one must be at work earlier, he can rely on this leniency. Apparently, many shuls in my neighborhood are doing just that, so there must be something allowable! You can't quite have a few hundred people and their rav be wrong on this all the time.

Comment: Where do we see that “fixed place for praying” trumps davening b'zman? e.g. if one's regular shul started davening early and locking the doors after, is there any reason to assume one may daven with them before the zman?

Comment: See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/118889/what-are-the-heterim-for-davening-before-neitz/118891#118891