# What are the heterim for davening before neitz?

Tags: halacha, shemoneh-esrei, shacharis-morning-prayer, hanetz-sunrise

These days, neitz (at least in the Northeast of America) is at approximately 7:10 AM. There are many minyanim that I've been to that daven at 6:50 or earlier throughout the year, all but guaranteeing that shemoneh esrei is being davened before neitz.

What are the heterim for this? When the sole reason to do so is because that's the time the minyan happens thoughout the year, what are the reasons why this is muttar and that minyanim do not push off davening to hit neitz (even when it's just a minute or two off)?

Comment: Um. Some people need to get to work.

Comment: Same hetter for davening after neitz:)

Comment: Thanks for the check. But note that DoubleAA had quite a number of detailed disagreements with my points, see the comments. I've tried to correct what I said as needed.

Comment: (Excuse the hebrew, but this is much simpler) בקיצור יש מחלוקת איך להגדיר תפילה כוותיקין, שלדעת הרי"ף זה לכתחילה ולהתפלל לפני הנץ זה בדיעבד, וכמו כן אחר הנץ, אבל לדעתו אין להתפלל לפני הנץ אלא בשעת הדחק, ואחר הנץ אם עבר על הדין של לכתחילה אפילו בפשיעה. ולדעת התוס' וותיקין הוא מצוה מן המובחר, ולהתפלל או לפני כן או אחרי כן הוא גם כן לכתחילה. באיגרת משה כותב כתוס', אבל נראה לי שמנהג הספרדים ומנהג א"י לחשוש יותר לשיטת הרי"ף.

Comment: @Mordechai Thank you, that's helpful. But note that that Igros Moshe there also included the Rif in his mechudashdik shitah (paraphrasing his words). What he was basically doing was moving the issue from tefillah to krias shema (same with R' Isser Zalman), and saying that the real problems are with doing krias shema too early. I think.

Comment: I presume that we're talking Shacharis here and not Maariv? :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that you are asking two different questions.
For the first, it is far from clear that davening before neitz is any problem compared to davening later - which I think you're assuming. The Shulchan Aruch uses a language of "b'diavad", but Igros Moshe (OH 4:6) and R' Isser Zalman (Even Ha'azel on the Rambam on Krias Shema, if I remember right) suggest that that means, compared to davening *exactly* at neitz or immediately just after. In their opinion, davening before neitz is no different from davening after neitz. I think the language of the [Tur (89)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tur%2C_Orach_Chaim.89.1?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) is especially clear:

> זמן תפלת השחר מתחיל משעלה עמוד השחר והאיר פני המזרח שהיא כנגד תמיד השחר ומאותה שעה ואילך הוא זמנה ומ"מ עיקר מצותה עם הנץ החמה אלא שאם התפלל משעלה עמוד השחר יצא ונמשך עד סוף ד' שעות
> The time of Shacharis begins with dawn and the brightening east, as [the prayer] corresponds to the Tamid of the morning. From then onward is its time - but the *main* mitzvah is [to pray] as the sun rises. But if he prayed from dawn he has fulfilled his obligation, and that continues until the end of the fourth hour.

I see that the [Mishnah Berurah (89:1)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.89.1?lang=bi&with=Mishnah%20Berurah&lang2=he) and others do agree with your assumption.
See the [Kaf Hachaim 89(3)](https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.89.3.1?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) who brings the פר"ח who learns the Shulchan Aruch the way I was describing, and who also does not seem to see any difference between before neitz and after it.
Later in that section, the [Shulchan Aruch (89:8)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.89.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he) talks about davening before משיכיר, before one can distinguish. That is a still earlier time and not advised because it interferes with other parts of davening or putting on tefillin.

For the second question, why not move it a few minutes to neitz? Some minyanim indeed do that. But when they asked R' Feivel Cohen shlit"a (the בדי השולחן), the Rav of the shul where I used to daven, he brushed off the idea: Some people daven neitz (the special people called vatikin, which Rashi describes as [Berachos 9b] "humble men who love mitzvos"), and they do it all year-round. The rest don't.
I don't know if other rabbanim agree with that idea or have some other reason. It certainly seems to be the minhag. My current synagogue has hundreds of members and only one Shacharis minyan: early, same time every morning.

Comment: This seems to miss the point. It is indeed debatable if there are rishonim who think before and after sunrise are equally not-vatikin, but there are undoubtedly rishonim who strongly prefer after sunrise to before it, so you still need to explain why not do it. And the second point, while the opinion of one rabbi, is not that helpful since it doesn't give a reason.

Comment: Once there are opinions that it is perfectly fine, the explanation is that these rabbonim and shuls poskin like the opinions that it is fine. I don't think the questioner knew that there are such opinions. [Nor has anyone here yet shown any other opinions!] And, Rav Feivel did indeed give a reason, which I quoted.

Comment: The reason you quoted is "because we don't". That's not a reason in any meaningful sense of the word. Like if you ask a kid why they like baseball and they say "because I do". That's not a reason in any meaningful sense of the word. It's just a tautology

Comment: you are incorrect to point that out since it's not true. Just because no one here has bothered citing the positions that forbid davening before sunrise unless necessary doesn't mean they don't exist. The Rambam for instance couldn't be clearer. So too Rabbenu Yonah. Both of whom the Shulchan Aruch tends to rule like regarding Shema times. The Shulchan Aruch even specifically changes the language of the Tur to remove your diyuk. Moreover from Rabbenus Chananel, Tam, and Zerachiah et al it's clear before sunrise isn't ideal even for shema!

Comment: @DoubleAA The reason Rav Feival was giving was that the people who do it are special people, as Rashi says. Ordinary people don't have that practice, and that is the minhag Yisroel everywhere I know of. A few special shuls daven vasikin and the rest don't. You are looking at Rishonim rather than looking at the way the minhag works currently. And I think you are misreading the Rambam to say he "forbids" this, certainly to say that he "could not be clearer"!

Comment: ואם התפלל תפילת שחרית בשעת הדוחק, אחר שעלה עמוד השחר--יצא. What is unclear? This is the Rambam in the paragraph about people who daven at the wrong time, not in the paragraph at the beginning where he discusses the correct time to daven.

Comment: Here's Rabbenu Yona, also clear as day https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%99%22%D7%A3_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9E%D7%94%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%AA_%D7%A9%22%D7%A1_%D7%95%D7%95%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%90_%D7%93%D7%A3_%D7%93_%D7%A2%22%D7%91 He writes that the vatikin wanted to read shema before sunrise, but if they read too early they wouldn't be able to daven then, so they had to read it just before sunrise.

Comment: Let's also look at Magen Avraham here 89 quoting Maharshal that we should be careful to not daven before sunrise and can only maybe allow it after early slichot if there's great Torach Tzibbur to gather again, like davening early maariv. Obviously, not agreeing with your position. See too Mishna Berura who rules against you, even in his Beiur Halacha where he quotes your opinion as arguing with the Shulchan Aruch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117175/discussion-between-michoelr-and-double-aa).

Comment: At least got a chance to look at the Igros Moshe and the Even Ha'azel on the Rambam. I guess my conclusion would be that the Mishnah Berurah and maybe the Magen Avraham and others agree with you, the Pri Chadash does not, but that the Mishnah Berurah is assuming that the Shulchan Aruch agrees with him, and the Igros Moshe and the Even Haazel (in the Rambam that is the source for the Shulchan Aruch) are not reading them that way at all. Igros Moshe, Talmidei Rabbeinu Yonah and the Rif as well. And of course there's the Tur, who is much clearer.

Comment: So I can't call it a mistake and I'll amend that. But I think the other side is making a mistake as well, missing that many of the Rishonim that they think "couldn't be clearer" may not be saying that. I did see that the Rambam says that saying Shema after neitz is "עבר ואיחר". They didn't see it as just a ma'aleh b'alma.

Comment: Anyhow, I'd like to ask Rav Feivel but don't get to talk to him often these days since he and I moved. He's really my source, if I'm remembering right. I don't know what-all he had in mind really, just these vague recollections.

Answer (score 4):

In [Shulchan Aruch O.C. 89:8](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x457) we find the following codification:

> בשעת הדחק כגון שצריך להשכים לדרך יכול להתפלל משעלה עמוד השחר
>
> Under pressing circumstances, e.g. that he needs to rise early for the road, one can pray from dawn.

Synagogues with early prayer services may be assuming that for for those who need to go to work it is considered a pressing circumstance.

Comment: I think you are making a mistake here. This part of the Shulchan Aruch is discussing davening before משיכיר - as it says, from dawn. The questioner is asking about davening near neitz: after משיכיר. For that you do not need "pressing circumstances".

Comment: @MichoelR Misheyakkir doesn't have anything to do with davening shacharis, only for saying shema.

Comment: @DoubleAA Still, it is clear from the discussion in that section that the Shulchan Aruch is working out how to arrange Krias Shema and its brachos around the fact that you already davened, "even though you won't be able to bring גאולה next to tefillah..."

Comment: @MichoelR he even discusses that. You are just making up what he says about a case he didn't think to distinguish

Comment: @DoubleAA To me he seems to be explaining why it is only permitted בשעת הדחק: because it makes a mess of the rest of the davening.

Comment: @Mic Youre just making that up. He doesn't say "because it messes" he says "and remember it messes" [meaning even though] because he's coming to negate the opinion that it's better to daven later without messing but without kavana. He says it explicitly. He says explicitly this is not zmanah. He says explicitly in seif 1 that zmanah is only after netz and before is only "yatza" clearly coming to reject the diyuk in the Tur you cite below. Its like "when stuck you can daven early even if you have to mess up the order of things" If ShA thought after misheyakir was different he could have said so

Comment: @DoubleAA I still don't understand. He is _only_ talking about before משיכיר. Every one of his comments only makes sense before משיכיר. "from dawn" "Wait to say shema..." etc. He doesn't need to "say so"; that is the context of the whole comment.

Comment: @DoubleAA Hard to see what you call "explicitly" in seif 1, where it can be read like the פר"ח - unless you tell me that in the Beis Yosef he mentioned anywhere that he disagrees with the Tur, or even noticed that the Tur was controversial.

Comment: @MichoelR My point above was he doesn't say misheyakkir (even the Tur doesn't, when he describes the case as פירוש, מקדמי לעיקר מצותה שהוא הנץ החמה, והיו הם מקדימין מעלות השחר why didn't the Tur say פירוש למשיכיר שאז אי אפשר לסמוך גל״ת). You're making an ukimta because it doesn't match with what you want him to hold but that's not the simple reading. What you say is hard to see wasn't hard for most acharonim, as the Beiur Halacha says היינו בדיעבד כמו שכתבתי במ"ב וכן העתיקו הרבה אחרונים והפר"ח חולק על השו"ע. I'm not saying everyone has to paskin like the ShA but we're discussing his opinion.

Comment: See too Beit Yosef who says  לכך נראה כפירוש ר"ח, דמשעלה עמוד השחר קאמר, והוו מקדמי קודם הנץ החמה ועדיין אינו עיקר זמן תפילה who doesn't say the kula is davening with messed up shema situation but rather that it is not the right time for prayer. (The modern perspective of birkos KrSh as part of davening which drives your suggested read is anachronistic here; when they talk about davening they mean davening.) Youre not only ukimta-ing a time limit but a reason as well, and it doesn't hold up.

Comment: והפר"ח חולק על השו"ע - hard to say that when the פר"ח says המחבר סתם בכאן ולא פירש והעיקר הוא כו. He definitely thinks that he is explaining the Shulchan Aruch, who was somewhat unclear.

Comment: @DoubleAA I think the Aruch Hashulchan (OH 89(29-the end) learns the seif like I'm saying. He mentions משיכיר many times, but never mentions נץ except at the beginning. "He waits to read ק"ש until its time - _which is משיכיר_... And he cannot wait in his house _until that time_ - because otherwise he would say Shema and pray [then]..." To him, the whole discussion is before v. after משיכיר.